# what's wrong with my mysql procedure (containing cursor)?

Tags: mysql, cursor, procedure

```
delimiter ;;
drop procedure if exists just_test;
create procedure just_test()
  begin
    declare id varchar(30);
    declare status tinyint;
    declare done tinyint default false;
    declare cur cursor for select id,status from bill where id = '123';
    declare continue HANDLER for not found set done = true;
    open cur;
    read_loop:loop
      if done then
        leave read_loop;
      end if ;
      insert into bill2 (id, status) values (id, status);
    end loop ;
    close cur;
  end ;;
delimiter ;
call just_test();
```

table bill is exists, bill2 is exists, record(id=123) is exists, I executed the code, nothing happen, no error, no hint, can you tell me why? thanks very much.

Comment: You aren't fetching anything from the cursor at any point. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fetch.html - and you have an infinite loop

Comment: Also, the loop  does not begin but ends  "end loop ;"  in your code :)

Answer (score 1):

You need no cursor for that

```
delimiter |
drop procedure if exists just_test;

create procedure just_test()
  begin
    insert into bill2 (id, status)
    select id, status from bill where id = '123';
  end |
delimiter ;

call just_test();
```

Comment: Thanks, Your advise for this sample is OK.but I ignored some details, actually, I used more actions, like case when etc. The conclusion is that I must use cursor without choices.

Comment: You can post the real query. Most of the time cursors can be avoided.